# Como passar o valor de uma variável para um input hidden?

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer para passar o `value` de uma variável Javascript para um `input hidden` ?

Answer (score 5):

Seria bom você colocar algum código mas basicamente com jquery seria assim:

```js
$("#botao").click(function(){
var minhaVariavel="valor";
  alert("Antes de atribuir o valor:"+$("input[name='campoInvisivel']").val());
$("input[name='campoInvisivel']").val(minhaVariavel);
alert("Depois de atribuir o valor:"+$("#campoInvisivel").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="campoInvisivel" id="campoInvisivel">
<input type="button" value="Colocar Valor com Jquery" id="botao">
```

Aqui o exemplo somente com JavaScript, lembrando que os `alert` são apenas para demonstração, a linha na qual passa o valor para o input é essa `document.getElementById("campoInvisiveljs").value=minhaVariavel;`. Segue abaixo o código completo

```js
// Aqui é só com js
function passarValor(){
var minhaVariavel="valor";
alert("Antes de passar o valor:"+ document.getElementById("campoInvisiveljs").value);
document.getElementById("campoInvisiveljs").value=minhaVariavel;
alert("Depois de passar o valor:"+document.getElementById("campoInvisiveljs").value);
}
```

```html
   <input type="hidden" name="campoInvisiveljs" id="campoInvisiveljs">
   <input type="button" value="Colocar Valor com Java Script" id="botao" onClick="passarValor();">
```

Comment: Não existe nenhuma forma mais simples com javascript?

Comment: Você quer somente com js, sem jquery?

Comment: o que voce nao achou simples?

Comment: Exato, quero somente com javascript.

Comment: Pronto, editei e deixei das duas formas para servir para outras pessoas posteriormente...

Answer (score 2):

Com javascript basta atribuir o valor ao atributo `value`:

```
var variavel = ["a", "b", "c"];
document.getElementById("input_hidden_id").value = variavel.join("");
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
    var variavel = ["a", "b", "c"];
    document.getElementById("input_hidden_id").value = variavel.join("");

    function verValor() {
      document.write(document.getElementById("input_hidden_id").value);
    }
```

```html
<input id="input_hidden_id" type="hidden" value="123" />
<button onclick="verValor()">Ver Valor</button>
```

Comment: Como posso passar uma array?

Comment: Pode usar a função `join()` que junta os valores do array. Editei a resposta @Gonçalo

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var dados = ['eu', 'tu', 'ele'];
var input = document.getElementById('escondido');
input.value = JSON.stringify(dados);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="escondido" />
```

Desse modo o `input` vai receber como valor um JSON que pode facilmente ser re-convertido em array no servidor ou quando se ler o valor dele.